# changing from JApplet to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, calculator

So i have this code that creates a Calculator in Java. But it is made with JApplet,and i need it to be with JFrame. What needs to be changed??

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Calculator extends JApplet {
   public void init() {
      CalculatorPanel calc=new CalculatorPanel();
      getContentPane().add(calc);
      }
   }

   class CalculatorPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
      JButton 
n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9,n0,plus,minus,mul,div,dot,equal;
      static JTextField result=new JTextField("0",45);
      static String lastCommand=null;
      JOptionPane p=new JOptionPane();
      double preRes=0,secVal=0,res;

      private static void assign(String no)
        {
         if((result.getText()).equals("0"))
            result.setText(no);
          else if(lastCommand=="=")
           {
            result.setText(no);
            lastCommand=null;
           }
          else
            result.setText(result.getText()+no);
         }

      public CalculatorPanel() {
         setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         result.setEditable(false);
         result.setSize(300,200);
         add(result,BorderLayout.NORTH);
         JPanel panel=new JPanel();
         panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));

         n7=new JButton("7");
         panel.add(n7);
         n7.addActionListener(this);
         n8=new JButton("8");
         panel.add(n8);
         n8.addActionListener(this);
         n9=new JButton("9");
         panel.add(n9);
         n9.addActionListener(this);
         div=new JButton("/");
         panel.add(div);
         div.addActionListener(this);

         n4=new JButton("4");
         panel.add(n4);
         n4.addActionListener(this);
         n5=new JButton("5");
         panel.add(n5);
         n5.addActionListener(this);
         n6=new JButton("6");
         panel.add(n6);
         n6.addActionListener(this);
         mul=new JButton("*");
         panel.add(mul);
         mul.addActionListener(this);

         n1=new JButton("1");
         panel.add(n1);
         n1.addActionListener(this);
         n2=new JButton("2");
         panel.add(n2);
         n2.addActionListener(this);
         n3=new JButton("3");
         panel.add(n3);
         n3.addActionListener(this);
         minus=new JButton("-");
         panel.add(minus);
         minus.addActionListener(this);

         dot=new JButton(".");
         panel.add(dot);
         dot.addActionListener(this);
         n0=new JButton("0");
         panel.add(n0);
         n0.addActionListener(this);
         equal=new JButton("=");
         panel.add(equal);
         equal.addActionListener(this);
         plus=new JButton("+");
         panel.add(plus);
         plus.addActionListener(this);
         add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
      }
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
         {
      if(ae.getSource()==n1) assign("1");
      else if(ae.getSource()==n2) assign("2");
      else if(ae.getSource()==n3) assign("3");
      else if(ae.getSource()==n4) assign("4");
      else if(ae.getSource()==n5) assign("5");
      else if(ae.getSource()==n6) assign("6");
      else if(ae.getSource()==n7) assign("7");
      else if(ae.getSource()==n8) assign("8");
      else if(ae.getSource()==n9) assign("9");
      else if(ae.getSource()==n0) assign("0");
      else if(ae.getSource()==dot)
            {
             if(((result.getText()).indexOf("."))==-1)
                result.setText(result.getText()+".");
           }
      else if(ae.getSource()==minus)
             {
             preRes=Double.parseDouble(result.getText());
             lastCommand="-";
             result.setText("0");
             }
      else if(ae.getSource()==div)
             {
             preRes=Double.parseDouble(result.getText());
             lastCommand="/";
             result.setText("0");
             }
      else if(ae.getSource()==equal)
             {
             secVal=Double.parseDouble(result.getText());
             if(lastCommand.equals("/"))
                  res=preRes/secVal;
             else if(lastCommand.equals("*"))
                  res=preRes*secVal;
             else if(lastCommand.equals("-"))
                  res=preRes-secVal;
             else if(lastCommand.equals("+"))
                  res=preRes+secVal;
             result.setText(" "+res);
             lastCommand="=";
             }
      else if(ae.getSource()==mul)
             {
              preRes=Double.parseDouble(result.getText());
              lastCommand="*";
              result.setText("0");
              }
      else if(ae.getSource()==plus)
              {
              preRes=Double.parseDouble(result.getText());
              lastCommand="+";
              result.setText("0");
              }

       }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simple Applets, this should do it

- extend JFrame (obviously)
- move stuff from init() to the constructor.

  ```
  public class Calculator extends JFrame{

    public Calculator() {
    CalculatorPanel calc=new CalculatorPanel();
    getContentPane().add(calc);
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
              System.exit(0);
          }
      });
     pack();
     setVisible(true);
    }
  ```

  }

Comment: While it is necessary to extend `JApplet`, it is neither necessary nor desirable to extend `JFrame` (unless the code provides extra methods beyond a standard `JFrame`).

Answer (score 2):

Nobody seems to have noticed that your SSCCE was very well suited to becoming an hybrid application/applet.  That is because the main GUI was coded in a `JPanel` (`CalculatorPanel`) that can then be added to either the `JApplet`, or a `JFrame`.

To create the hybrid, change the first lines of the source to:

```
// <applet code='Calculator' width='400' height='450'></applet>
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Calculator extends JApplet {
   public void init() {
      CalculatorPanel calc=new CalculatorPanel();
      getContentPane().add(calc);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Runnable r = new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Calculator");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.add(new CalculatorPanel());
            f.pack();
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
      };
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
   }
}
```

Then, to compile & run it as both an applet & application, something like..

```
prompt> javac Calculator.java
prompt> appletviewer Calculator.java  // run the applet
prompt> java Calculator               // run the application
```

Answer (score 1):

Not too much

```
public class Calculator extends JFrame{   //1
   public void init() {
      CalculatorPanel calc=new CalculatorPanel();
      getContentPane().add(calc);
      this.show();       //2
      }
   }
```

and a main function of course...

Answer (score 1):

Awful code... ;-)

Anyway, with simple changes, it works:

```
public class Calculator
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    // creating and showing this application's GUI.
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        JFrame calc = new JFrame();
        CalculatorPanel display = new CalculatorPanel();
        calc.add(display);
        calc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        calc.pack();
        calc.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  static class CalculatorPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener 
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a JApplet to a JFrame by:

```
    JFrame f=new JFrame();
    f.setSize(x, y);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);

    Calculator calculator=new Calculator();
    calculator.setSize(x, y);

    f.add(calculator);
```

**EDIT**:

[Here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/28410-application-to-japplet-and-reverse/) is a tutorial for it.

Comment: You are welcome. Remember to mark any answer which you feel works for you as an accepted one.